# How to get the grammar production when there is an error with Ply(Yacc)?

Tags: python-3.x, yacc, ply

In the `yacc.py` file I defined the output of a grammar and also an error, like this:

```
def p_error(p):
  if p:
    print("Error when trying to read the symbol '%s' (Token type: %s)" % (p.value, p.type))
  else:
    print("Syntax error at EOF")
  exit()
```

In addition to this error message, I also want to print what was the production read at the time of the error, something like:

```
print("Error in production: ifstat -> IF LPAREN expression RPAREN statement elsestat")
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Really, you can't. You particularly can't with a bottom-up parser like the one generated by Ply, but even with top-down parsers "the production read at the time"  is not a very well-defined concept.

For example, consider the erroneous code:

```
if (x < y return 42;
```

in which the error is a missing parentheses. At least, that's how I'd describe the error. But a closing parenthesis is not the only thing which could follow the 0. For example, a correct program might include any of the following:

```
if (x < y) return 42;
if (x < y + 10) return 42;
if (x < y && give_up_early) return 42;
```

and many more.

So which production is the parser trying to complete when it sees the token `return`? Evidently, it's still trying to complete `expression` (which might actually have a hierarchy of different expression types, or which might be relying on precedence declarations to be a single non-terminal, or some combination of the two.) But that doesn't really help identify the error as a missing close parenthesis.

In a top-down parser, it would be possible to walk up the parser stack to get a list of partially-completed productions in inclusion order. (At least, that would be possible if the parser maintained its own stack. If it were a recursive-descent parser, examining the stack would be more complicated.)

But in a bottom-up parser, the parser state is more complicated. Bottom-up parsers are more flexible than top-down parsers precisely because they can, in effect, consider multiple productions *at the same time*. So there often really isn't one single partial production; the parser will decide which production it is looking at by gradually eliminating all the possibilities which don't work.

That description makes it sound like the bottom-up parser is doing a lot of work, which is misleading. The work was already done by the parser generator, which compiles a simple state transition table to guide the parse. What that means in practice is that the parser knows how to handle every possibly-correct token at each moment in the parse. So, for example, when it sees a `)` following `if (x < y`, it immediately knows that it must finish up the `expression` production and proceed with the rest of the `if` statement.

Bison -- a C implementation of yacc -- has an optional feature which allows it to list the possible correct tokens when an error is encountered. That's not as simple as it sounds, and implementing it correctly creates a noticeable overhead in parsing time, but it is sometimes useful. (It's often not useful, though, because the list of possible tokens can be very long. In the case of the error I'm using as an example, the list would include every single arithmetic operator, as well as those tokens which could start a postfix operator. The bison extended error handler stops trying when it reaches the sixth possible token, which means that it will rarely generated an extended error message if the parse is in the middle of an expression.) In any case, Ply does not have such a feature.

Ply, like bison, does implement error recovery through the `error` pseudo-token. The error-recovery algorithm works best with languages which have an unambiguous resynchronisation point, as in languages with a definite statement terminator (unlike C-like languages, in which many statements do not end with `;`). But you can use `error` productions to force the parser to pop its stack back to some containing production in order to produce a better error message. In my experience, a lot of experimentation is needed to get this strategy right.

In short, producing meaningful error messages is hard. My recommendation is to first focus on getting your parser working on correct inputs.

Comment: But can I know the last state covered before giving an error?

Comment: @devmaster: The error occurs in a particular state when that state has no transition on the lookahead symbol. The state number is not publicly available (and might not be available at all, depending on how table compression is performed). There are some hacks, though. See, for example, https://research.swtch.com/yyerror

Comment: @devmaster: I should add that you will need a thorough understanding of the parser algorithm to use that information. In particular, you'll need to deal with default reductions. Read the section in the bison manual about [LAC](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#LAC)